findFirst error when trying to read data from primsa - shopify app
the full error - https://pastebin.com/raw/0itVDGjJ
I have created the setting model and am trying to read and write to that model but I'm facing issue
export async function loader() {
    let settings = await db.settings.findFirst();
    console.log('settings - ',settings);
    return json(settings);
}

export async function action({ request}) {
    let settings = await request.formData();
    settings = Object.fromEntries(settings);

    await db.settings.upsert({
      where: {
        id: '1'
      },
      update: {
        id: '1',
        name: settings.name,
        description: settings.description
      },
      create: {
        id: '1',
        name: settings.name,
        description: settings.description
      }
    });

    return json(settings);
}

above mentioned is the code, not sure what mistake I made.
I was following https://youtu.be/lLRdJdTnzoU?list=PLB4AdipoHpxZu39dNjUWGRwgeKgW7mVJ-
repo - https://github.com/arkodeepg/wishlist/
